# Conditionally displaying data from XML using XSLT1?

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is a XML snippet:

```
<div class="headingZoom">
  <xsl:text>Congregation Meeting Schedule for </xsl:text>  
  <xsl:value-of select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[1]/MeetingDate/@MonthFull"/>
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[1]/MeetingDate/@Year"/>

  <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>

  <xsl:value-of select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[last()]/MeetingDate/@MonthFull"/>
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[last()]/MeetingDate/@Year"/>

  <xsl:value-of select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[last()]/SpecialEvent/Date/@MonthFull"/>
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[last()]/SpecialEvent/Date/@Year"/>
</div>
```

The problem is that the last element will be one or the other:

- This one:

```
<xsl:value-of select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[last()]/MeetingDate/@MonthFull"/>
<xsl:text> </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[last()]/MeetingDate/@Year"/>
```

- Or this one:

```
<xsl:value-of select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[last()]/SpecialEvent/Date/@MonthFull"/>
<xsl:text> </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[last()]/SpecialEvent/Date/@Year"/>
```

How can I do that with XSLT-1?

---

Infact, upon reflection, even this bit needs to apply the same logic where I display the data for `Meeting[1]`. It too could be one or the other type of element.

I should point out that it would never have both in teh relevant nodes, just one or the other.

Comment: So in the input both `Meeting[1]` and `Meeting[last()]` either have a `MeetingDate` child with the relevant data to output or a `SpecialEvent` child element with the relevant data to output? Then process `<xsl:apply-templates select="Meeting[1] | Meeting[last()]"/>` and set up templates for `Metting/MeetingDate` and `Meeting/SpecialEvent` outputting the details you need.

Comment: @martin-honnen Understood. Did not think of that! And I can use Mode can’t I to limit to certain template. Since I already have proper templates for full processing.

Comment: Yes, sure, use a mode if you need to process the same type of nodes twice in different ways. Or perhaps the shortcut presented in the proposed answer suffices to handle your two cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:value-of select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[last()]//@MonthFull"/>
<xsl:text> </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting[last()]//@Year"/>
```

Please note the double slash.